# ASP.net merge with an existing database?

Tags: asp.net, sql, entity-framework

I have a database that's been populated with data on a server. I've made some 
changes to the database models and I wish to merge the existing data with the new data without losing everything.

Do you know of an appropriate and no-nonsense method to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well one method would be to set up replication from each of them to a single database. But that seems pretty time intensive. I think you might have to write a program to do it (either .net or SQL) because how would it know which record to take if you have two records with the same primary key?

If you know that there will never be any duplicates, you could just write sql statements to do it. But that's a pretty big if.

You might try something like http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-data-compare/ which will synchronize data and I believe it will also figure out what to do when there are two records. I've had very good luck with Red-Gate products.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I'm going to try out the Red Gate product and see if it works. Thanks for your concise and straight forward answer.